# How to tackle Different values passed by android studio in debug and run mode caused by network connection check

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android app which checks for availability of a website and then passes a message "Website Connected" if the website is available or "Website Down...please try again later" if the website is not available.

However I have noticed that the app works fine when I debug it, **but** if I normally run the app the from android studio it gives wrong message irrespective if the website is connected or not.

Below is my code :-

```
 public boolean process() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do the processing.
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                String link = "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=5yZ0VoqxOMWM8QfW057wBQ";//this site was used to check for returning a valid connection
            //   String link="http://www.afjndfns.com/";//this site was used to check for returning not a valid connection
                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(link);
                        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200)
                        {        // 200 = "OK" code (http connection is fine).

                            connection=true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            connection=false;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.print("IOexception"+e);

                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return  connection;
    }
```

The variable connection is a gloabal variable set to false by default.

In my `onCreate` method I have the TextView Setter.

```
        if(process()==true)
        {
            tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvIsConnected.setText("Website Connected");
        }
        else
        { // code if not connected
            tvIsConnected.setText("Website Down...please try again later");
        }
```

I have tried this code on Android Studio version v.2.0 preview 3 and v.1.3.

UPDATE : As @comrade suggested debug threads run slow compared to run threads, so I had to make my own async task whuch runs on separate thread and checks for the website's status.  See my answer.

Comment: Are you just trying to determine whether you have an internet connection, or do you care specifically about this one website's availability?

Comment: i want to knw the availability of this specific website only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onCreate` method call an Asynctask class which checks for connection in background.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
       new ConCheck().execute();
}
```

Connection Checker class

```
 class ConCheck extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait....");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Establishing connection to Server...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                        // Do the check for connection.
                 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                 NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                 String link = "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=5yZ0VoqxOMWM8QfW057wBQ";//pass your site here for connection checking
                 if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                     try {
                            URL url = new URL(link);
                             HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                             if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200)
                              {        // 200 = "OK" code (http connection is fine).
                                    connection=true;
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  connection=false;
                              }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                System.out.print("IOexception"+e);

                            }
                        }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //do your post checking work here.
            if(connection)
            {
                tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
                tvIsConnected.setText("Servers Connected");
            }
            else
            { // code if connected
                //tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
                tvIsConnected.setText("Server Down...please try again later");

            }
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Basically this class checks whethere a website or server is available or not. Honestly I could not find a better answer anywhere in StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

When you run in DEBUG mode it's a bit "slower" than in NORMAL so your thread has a chance to finish work and return correct result.

You need to use correct logic for async requests. You can use AsyncTask for example and update tvIsConnected in onPostExecute method of task. For more information about AsyncTask check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and about asynchronous work check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Comment: thankyou, i wrote my code now, check my answer as it correctly tackles the situation

Answer (score 0):

> hi.you can use unvisible webView.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        isPageLoaded=true; 
        return isPageLoaded; 
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if(isPageLoading) {
            tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvIsConnected.setText("Website Connected");
        }
     }
});
```